# Issue with react-styleguidist -resolving node dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, react-styleguidist

I'm using React Styleguidedist to generate documentation for my react components. While building we are getting the following error (yarn).

> error
>   "react-styleguidist#react-docgen-displayname-handler#react-docgen@2.x"
>   doesn't satisfy found match of "react-docgen@3.0.0-beta6"

Any pointers would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a warning, you can safely ignore it.

P. S. Anyway I’ve submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/nerdlabs/react-docgen-displayname-handler/pull/1) to react-docgen-displayname-handler that should fix that.